# React : Best practice to handle complex objects passed as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Lets assume I have a React component (*functional component*) and i am passing multiple props. One of these props is a nested object like...

**Example nested object**

```
const user = {
    id: 101,
    email: 'jack@dev.com',
    personalInfo: {
        name: 'Jack',
        address: {
            line1: 'westwish st',
            line2: 'washmasher',
            city: 'wallas',
            state: 'WX'
        }
    }
}
```

For simplicity I want to pass the whole object, but instead of accessing it via *user.personalInfo.adress.line1* I would like to save this to variable.

I am passing it to the following component...

**Example React Component**

```
const ExampleComponent = (props) => {
    
    // Example 1
    const [state1, setState1] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        setState1(user.personalInfo.adress.line1);
    })
    
    // Example 2
    const state1Var = user.personalInfo.adress.line1
}
```

I know that saving props to states is a **bad practice**. (= Example1) So whats the smartest way to do that?
Saving it to a class variable? (= Example2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a state for this. You can simply destructure the object on render of components.

Note: using `useEffect` without dependency variable, will retrigger the callback function on each render. It will be a memory issue `useEffect(() => {},[])`.

```js
const user = {
  id: 101,
  email: "jack@dev.com",
  personalInfo: {
    name: "Jack",
    address: {
      line1: "westwish st",
      line2: "washmasher",
      city: "wallas",
      state: "WX",
    },
  },
};
const ExampleComponent = ({ user = {} }) => {
  const { personalInfo = {} } = user;
  const { name = "somedefault name", address = {} } = personalInfo;

  return (
    <div>
      {name}
      <br />
      {address.line1}
      <br />
      {address.line2}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with passing complex objects as props. Why do you need to save it to state? Just destructure the object in the child component (assuming it is not possibly null or undefined). React functional components are *just functions*, you don't need to save something to state in order to use it. Since you're passing it as a prop from a parent component, presumably the parent component keeps track of its state; when the parent state updates, the prop will change and your child component will rerender (or, in other words, your child component's function will be called with the new prop value(s)).

```
const ExampleComponent = (props) => {
    const {personalInfo} = props.user;

    /* ... */
}
```